# concurrent read with update in spring data

Tags: java, oracle, concurrency, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have two instances of same application which uses ONE database (oracle).
Applications based on Spring Data (CrudRepository).

**problem:** 
each app instance need to read rows from table and lock them to prevent reading (and handling) from another instance. I implemented it by CRUD repo *read list* method. and then for each item in list I set property **busy** and call CRUD *save* method for each. 
But it's not really concurrency safe: second instance can read the same list before the first instance marks each item as **busy** and save.

I have idea to update each row with some UID at the beginning and then get list with this UID. but it's like spike

How can I solve it? Transactions? Locks? Thx

Comment: A database lock will prevent changes across the different instances, but will not prevent reading the data. Look at `select ... for update` for a row lock in the table on Oracle.

Comment: it's using query... I need solution using ORM (Spring data/Hibernate).
`@Lock` annotation looks like `select ... for update`